# Passar dados via POST em AngularJS para API PHP

Tags: angularjs

Boa tarde

Preciso passar dados via post usando angularjs para uma api php os dados aparecem na controller mas não na api PHP.

```
if( isset($_REQUEST['mes']) ) {
    $mes = $_REQUEST['mes'];
} else {
    $mes = date('m');
}
```

Na controller visualizo os dados de formulario (mes e origem ):

```
.controller('AcpBuscaCtrl', function($scope, ApiAcp, $ionicLoading, $timeout, $http, $q) {  
  $scope.pesquisaAcp = function(data ) {
    $scope.mes = data.mes;
    $scope.origem = data.origem;
    $ionicLoading.show({
      noBackdrop: false,
      template: '<p>Pesquisando dados! aguarde ...</p>'
    });
    var q = $q.defer();
    $http.get(ApiAcpEndpoint.url, data)
      .then(function(data) {      
         console.log(' - data.mes '+$scope.mes);
         console.log(' - data.origem '+$scope.origem);

          var acompanhamento = {};
          acompanhamento.dados = [ data ];
          $scope.data = acompanhamento.dados;
          console.log('pesquisaAcompanhamento data :'+$scope.data);

          q.resolve(data);
          $ionicLoading.hide();

          console.log(' q.promise '+q.promise);
          return q.promise;
      });
  }
})
```

E em services tambem porem o resultado da pesquisa nao retorna:

```
.factory('ApiAcp', function($http, $q, ApiAcpEndpoint) {
    var getApiData = function(data) {    
    var q = $q.defer();    
    $http.get(ApiAcpEndpoint.url,data)
    .success(function(data) {
      q.resolve(data);
    })
    .error(function(error){
      console.log('Had an error'+error)
      q.reject(error);
    })
    return q.promise;
  }
  return {
    getApiData: getApiData    
  };
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por motivos que até hoje eu não sei quais são, quando o angular passa um post pro php você não consegue pegar da forma tradicional, tente da seguinte maneira:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

Fonte: http://devzone.co.in/angularjs-simple-example-post-data-php-page/

Comment: Isso acontece por que os inputs são enviados via body no formato json.

Answer (score 0):

Bom pelo seu código vc não está efetuando um post e sim um get...
tanto no controller como no factory, substitui como abaixo e teste seu código...ABÇ!

```js
$http.post(ApiAcpEndpoint.url, data)
      .then(function(data) {      
         console.log(' - data.mes '+$scope.mes);
         console.log(' - data.origem '+$scope.origem);

          var acompanhamento = {};
          acompanhamento.dados = [ data ];
          $scope.data = acompanhamento.dados;
          console.log('pesquisaAcompanhamento data :'+$scope.data);

          q.resolve(data);
          $ionicLoading.hide();

          console.log(' q.promise '+q.promise);
          return q.promise;
      });
```

Factory:

```js
$http.post(ApiAcpEndpoint.url,data)
    .success(function(data) {
      q.resolve(data);
    })
    .error(function(error){
      console.log('Had an error'+error)
      q.reject(error);
    })
```

Problema que se você for executar um "get" realmente os parâmetros não seguem "$http.get(linkAPI, parametros)" e sim $http.get(linkAPI+?+parametros)...ABÇ!

Comment: me enganei e postei um teste que havia feito com get, este codigo com post nao chega a entregar os dados para a api php, mesmo que pelo console.log os dados cheguem na controller